# using multithread program to receive and organize a serial message (in C++)

Tags: multithreading, multidimensional-array, serial-port, mutex, critical-section

I'm new with programing multithreads things, so I'm wondering if anyone could help me.

I have to make a program that receives a serial (and continuous) asynchronized message, and then read it and organize this message.

I'm trying to use a multithread tactic: the first thread is responsible to receive the serial info and write it in a matrix (RxTh[col][row]), *one line at a time*. 
Then, the 2nd thread is called, to read each line of the RxTh matrix and search for specific chars (that symbolizes the 'begin line' msg). This thread also have to put this received messages in another matrix (Msg[col2][row2]) separating each line of the msg in a different row in the new matrix.

In the future, I'll have to work with this rearranged lines, and search for specifics information, but I'm not thinking in this part right now.

So, I'm having some problems with this program:

- First, I'm losing some pieces of the serial message when I stopped writing to begin the read part. That’s why I've tried to use mutex, or critical section. But it isn't working, and I don’t know why.
- The second problem, is that the second matrix (Msg[][]) has strange sequences of '0' in the middle of some lines, and I'm suspecting that this '0' appears while this thread starts to read a new row of the RxTh matrix. Does it make any sense?
- When I use mutex, can I lock only one row at a time?

If someone could help me, I'll appreciate a lot!!

If you need more information or a piece of the code, just ask me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a queue of buffers. Your matrix is only replicating this, but is confusing and don't carry metadata (a data about data).

1) define a class or structure containing a buffer+ some info about what's in this buffer (like how much data has been written to it). Like:

```
class Buff
{
    char contents[1024]; //(this represents your row)
    int numWritten;
    ...
}
```

2) create a FIFO queue guarded by a critical section.

now Thread1 creates `new` buffer, fills it and acquires critical section, pushes the buffer on the end of the queue, and releases critical section.

Thread2 acquires critical section, takes first buffer out of queue, releases critical section.
After it's done with processing the buffer, deletes it.

You'll need some additional synchronization, so thread2 can wait if there are no more full buffers to process. Also thread1 should pause if number of filled buffers is too high, to give thread2 more time.

If you feel that creating and deleting buffers might be not optimal then make some buffer manager. It'll hold predefined number of buffers (number of columns). Thread1 will take a buffer from that pool instead of `new` and thread2 will return them to the pool instead of `delete`.

You can easily lock one buffer at a time if you make separate mutex for every buffer. But it's not necessary in situation where only one thread is sending and one is receiving.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have some questions...
I don't know how to create a FIFO queue guarded by a critical section.
Can you show me some example code, to help me get the idea?

Thanks

Comment: @NatCruella It's just a list. Any list which keeps order will do. FIFO means you put new items at the end, and take them from the start (or oposite, it's a matter of your choice).

Comment: "Guarded by critical section" it's also just a programmer's approach to using it. It simply means that thread must acquire critical section (or a mutex, or semaphore, or whatever thread sync you like) before accessing the queue. You can simply make sure that in every piece of code accessing the queue, the critical scection is acquired before, and released after. Or create an object that encapsulates the queue and critsection as private members. An the only exposed public methods are Add() and Remove(), and in those methods the critection is acquired, list accessed and critsection released.

Comment: Oh, I got it!
Thanks very much!!